# Creating custom values for a histogram

Tags: data, histograms

Let's consider the following test case

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Nt = 1000;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Nt];

P0 = Histogram[data, {0, 1, 0.001}, "Probability", ChartStyle -> Gray,
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "P"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
PlotRange -> {0, 0.006}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

My question is: how can I multiply the values of the vertical axis by 1000?

**EDIT**

A part of the actual data can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/krpijsadsvqwz6n/data_hist.dat/file)

Then the code is

```
P0 = Histogram[d0, {0, 2 \[Pi], 0.001}, "Probability", 
ChartStyle -> Gray, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "P"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
PlotRange -> {0, 0.0012}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550]
```

Comment: I'm curious:  why would you want such a display?  It seems not to summarize the data very well.  In fact, it looks like a way to compact table a table of numbers and observed frequencies but again not so much of a summary.

Comment: Doesn't using `"Count"` instead of `"Probability"` do what you want? I'm assuming that the multiplier of 1,000 is because `Nt = 1000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom height function (you also need to change the plot range accordingly). The height function pure function takes a list of counts as the second argument, so to compute 1000 times the probability you just use:

```
1000 #2/Total[#2]&
```

Changing the plot range to 1000 times the previous plot range yields:

```
Histogram[
    data,
    {0,1,0.001},
    1000 #2/Total[#2]&,
    PlotRange->{0,6},
    ChartStyle->Gray,ChartBaseStyle->EdgeForm[None],Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"x","P"},
    RotateLabel->False,LabelStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Helvetica",20],
    PlotRangePadding->0,PlotRangeClipping->True,AspectRatio->1,ImageSize->550
]
```

[image]

Comment: When I apply this method to my actual data I get the following error message: Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z What gets echoed when you use `1000 Echo[#2]/Total[#2]&` instead?

Comment: A lot of zeroes.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z What does the Histogram look like when you use "Probability" instead?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I saw your edit. You didn't answer my question, though. When i try using your code with your dataset, I get lots of errors and the Histogram never finishes. Before switching from "Probability" to my suggested pure function, make sure Histogram works with "Probability". Probably your data set should be flattened before use?

Comment: Yes, with "probability" there is no error and the histogram is produced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94692/discussion-between-carl-woll-and-vaggelis-z).

Comment: OK, I found the error. I was using unflattened data, as you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at  `P0 // InputForm` you will see that the graphics are a series of rectangles.

For this example (with `PlotRange->All`) you can replace the rectangles with the following rule.

```
P0 /. Rectangle[{x1_Real, 0}, {x2_Real, y_Real}, "RoundingRadius" -> 0] -> 
      Rectangle[{x1,      0}, {x2,      1000*y}, "RoundingRadius" -> 0]
```

which results in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And what if the original histogram has a specific range, such as `PlotRange -> {0, 0.001}`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the desired transformation is linear we can simply rescale the tick labels (using `` Charting`FindTicks ``) for the vertical axis without having to worry about modifying the third argument of `Histogram`:

```
 Row[{Show[P0, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.15]], 
  Show[P0, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1000}], Automatic}, 
     {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   ImagePadding -> Scaled[.15]]}]
```

[image]

**Note:** The option `ImagePadding->Scaled[.15]` is added so that the image sizes of the two objects in `Row` are the same (Without it, because of different label sizes, the sizes of the plot areas will be different).

Answer (score 0):

If the multiplication by 1,000 is because `Nt = 1000`, then using `Automatic` or `"Count"` will get you what you want.  (If you want an arbitrary multiplicative constant other than the value of `Nt` - and are not interested in using `"Density"`, then it might help if you might give a rationale for doing so.)

```
Nt = 1000;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Nt];

Histogram[data, {0, 1, 0.001}, Automatic, ChartStyle -> Gray, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "P"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 6}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image: Histogram with counts]

I don't see that this is a particular useful display of the data.  You might want to try `SmoothKernelDistribution` instead (but using the `"Bounded"` option if your real data is bounded on the left and/or right).